# Single quote in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and I have a problem when I try to add single quote to the database. Everything else works perfect but if my text have single quote it won't work.

If I try to add for example 'test' and if I then click on source in a CKEditor toolbar I see 'test' , but when I want to add it to the database it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your server code because you don't handle properly user input.
Instead of building SQL sentences, use prepared statements to insert/update your data.

Comment: But the problem is that CKEditor does not send anything to the php script where I need to clear the data and save it to the database. If I add something without single quotes it works perfect, but with a single quote it sends nothing.

Comment: CKEditor doesn't send anything, it either replaces a textarea or you are reading the data back from the editor and sending it to your server, so check if you're doing correctly those steps.

Comment: But when I send some text without single quotes it works perfect.

Comment: So that means that your code is bug-free? Why don't you really take a look at what's the data being sent and how do you handle it in your server?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am experiencing a similar problem.